# algorithm to check if an array (with 9 positions) has the integers 1 to 9,independent of how they are sorted

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

what do you guys think a good algorithm would be to check (returning true) if an array of size 9, has the numbers 1 to 9, however they may be sorted.

I was thinking of creating an array V already initialized with the integers 1 to 9, then compare the first element of the first array with the each element of V, if it matched, replace the element of V with -1, then when we are finished we should check if we have an array V full of -1's. What you guys think of this idea of mine?

Thanks!

Comment: sort them and then check each number is = index+1, first failure return false

Comment: So for each element in the one array, you will examine each element of the other? There's surely a more performant alternative.

Comment: There's only 9 elements - is performance really a concern?

Comment: @PeterKelly, I'm assuming that in asking for an algorithm such as this, it is an educational exercise and would eventually be applied to something larger than a simple 9 element array. In which case, you would want something that could scale.

Comment: The number of answers proposing inefficient solutions really surprises me

Comment: ...sorting does look like a bit inefficient...

Comment: @dasen you can sort an array of integers in O(n) time, and no other way to do this will be asymptotically faster anyway because it potentially has to scan the entire input.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I don't assume anything - I just read the spec (question) :) I think my solution is easy to understand and works well for the question presented.

Answer (score 2):

1. create a BitSet in the function
2. do an iteration through the passed in vector, using the value as the position in the BitSet
3. If the position is already set, it's a dup, so return false
4. If at the end, and the length of the BitSet is 9, return true...

Comment: what's wrong with this - it's not the same as the OP's solution, and will handle arbitrary length arrays (well upto whatever maximum BitSet supports)...

Comment: You'll have to use `value - 1` as the position or the length will be 10.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array A indexed by values you want seen. Each element will be initially 0 and you will set A[i]  (if unset) to 1 if i is an element of the input and increment a counter. At the end the counter needs to be 9.

Comment: @ElKamina, Not identical, this removes an additional scanning to count and a scan for each seen test.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
public static boolean check1_9(int arr[]) {
    if (arr == null || arr.length != 9) {
        return false;
    }
    int mask = 0;
    for (int val : arr) {
        mask |= (1 << val);
    }
    return mask == (1 << 10) - 2; // true iff bits 1..9 are set
}
```

Comment: I know what you did there ; )  But still, the last line is a bit cryptic.  I find it clearer to shift by *(val - 1)* and to compare at the end with 0x1FF.  Pick your poison ; )

Comment: @ElKamina: Come again? (Ideally, with a specific counterexample where this wouldn't work for the OP's problem)

Comment: i think all the upvoted solutions here are O(1) mem and time ;)

Comment: @aix What if array has numbers from 1 to a million?

Comment: @ElKamina: That is not the OP's question. You are just arbitrarily making stuff up.

Answer (score 0):

multiply all array elements. if they equal `1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9` then you're good.

Comment: what about 1*2*9*4*5*2*7*8*9??

Comment: Sometimes I wish for a "like" button that is distinct from an upvote.

Comment: It really depends on how you'd like to handle elements appearing twice or more often. If they aren't allowed, this solution will work (assuming your number range is small enough).

Comment: I don't think there was any restriction on the number range. Otherwise the trivial solution would be just to check for the existence of any repeats. If there are any repeats then you have all nine numbers.

Comment: @soulcheck: I'll up it up!  Multiply all and see if they're equal to 9! but then also add them all and see if they sum to (n*n+1)/2.  Ah!  Now we're waiting another counter-example : )

Comment: Close, but no cigar: 2 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 14 : same product, same sum

Comment: @HansLub you're right, the code should also check if all values are smaller than 10

Answer (score 0):

Let's try it with a `boolean` array:

```
static boolean distinct9(final int... a) {
    return a.length == 9 && check(a);
}

static boolean check(final int... a) {
    final boolean[] b = new boolean[a.length];
    for (final int i : a) {
        final int j = i - 1;
        if (j < 0 || j >= b.length || b[j]) {
            return false;
        }
        b[j] = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

We iterate through the `int` array and use the numbers as indices in the `boolean` array. If the index is out of bounds, then there is a number too low or too high. If the `boolean` at the index is `true`, then there's a duplicate. If it is not, set it to `true` and continue with the next number.

If none of the negative criterias in the loop match, the check succeeds.

Answer (score -1):

Does it have to be an array? If you use Collections, you can use `set1.containsAll(set2);`

Answer (score -1):

Just use a second array as your "check list" to see missing entries (note this is pseudo code):

```
function all_in(arraytocheck) {
    array check = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    foreach(element in arraytocheck) {
        if(check[element]) // use this line
            return false;  // and this one, if you don't want to allow entries twice
        check[element] = 1;
    }

    foreach(element in check)
        if(!element)
            return false; // return false if an element is missing
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the size of the array is 9, then you just have to check that every number from 1 to 9 is contained in the array.
One way to do this is :

```
public boolean check(Integer[] array) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        if (!list.contains(i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Another way would be to do this :

```
public boolean check(Integer[] array) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);
    return list.containsAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Sort them, then check if each number = index+1. Return false at first failure, true otherwise.

Comment: Your solution's complexity O(nlogn). You can do O(n).

Comment: Then why use your algorithm? What is the point of giving a inefficient solution?

Comment: Why are you concerned about efficiency for working with an array with 9 elements?